# How to get access token for admin.directory.userlist api?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have created a gmail addon. i am trying to call api 
`curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed`

```
var loggedUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var domain = loggedUser.split('@')[1];
do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: domain,
    maxResults: 100,
    pageToken: pageToken,
   });
   var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
       for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          var user = users[i];
          emails.push(user.primaryEmail);
       }
     } else {
       Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
   } while (pageToken);
```

I have added all the required scopes
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user`
 in my appmanifest. if i try to hit the api directly i am getting 401. after giving scopes if i had to call this api manually can someone help me how to get access_token and api_key for calling api?

Comment: Resources>Use advanced services

Comment: Yeah i was actually using advanced services. then i am able to get those details. but when i deploy app to my domain market place the same api is not working. i added ADMIN SDK to my app from google cloud console. but i am not able to call this api. can you help me on how to make it work? I need to get all users of my domain

Comment: @TheMaster i am trying to get domain users like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory). will it work after deploying to marketplace or do i need to change anything

Comment: *same api is not working.* Could you [edit] your question to  add more specific  details? What's the error? What's the code? On which line is the error? Who are the users?  This might help others to find a solution.

Comment: If you must use `UrlFetchApp`, then you must send headers like you've sent in curl. Show  your fetchapp code and/or advanced services code.

Comment: @TheMaster updated the question with the sameple code. i enabled admin directory from resources > use advanced services. after deploying app to marketplace this is not working. i am not getting any of the data which i used to get before.

Comment: @vinaynarayana - could you also please help determine what are **emails** & **primaryEmail**? I think I may have a solution but the code errors out indicating that these are not defined.

Comment: @TheMaster **emails** is just a Array to store all domain users emails and **primaryEmail** is the key name which i will get from gmail domain object.

Answer (score 1):

### This works for me:

- Perform an URL fetch request with [`ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()) for authorization
- Add within the [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/manifests) the scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"
- Whitelist within the manifest file the requested URL

Sample code:

```
...
var loggedUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var domain = loggedUser.split('@')[1];
  var pageToken;
  var emails=[];
do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: domain,
    maxResults: 100,
  //  pageToken: pageToken,
   });

  var url='https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain='+domain;
      var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "pageToken": pageToken,    
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
   "contentType": "application/json",       
   }
  var page = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options));  
  Logger.log(page);
   var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
       for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          var user = users[i];
          emails.push(user.primaryEmail);
       }
     } else {
       Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
   } while (pageToken);
...
```

appsscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "AdminDirectory",
      "serviceId": "admin",
      "version": "directory_v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "DOMAIN",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" ],
   "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain="
  ],
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "MYSELF"
  },
  "gmail": {
    "name": "XXX",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/XXX.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "XXX"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": ["https://mail.google.com/"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked for me also. but the problem here is this API works only for admin users. if we try to use it for non-admin users it is giving error **GoogleJsonResponseException: Not Authorized to access this resource/API.**. Is there any other API to make it work for all users?

Comment: The permissions for AdminDirectory are not related to the API you use, but rather to the settings in the admin console. If you go to https://admin.google.com/ -> Directory -> Users, click on a user and select "Admin roles and privileges", you can change the role of a user or create a custom role, to assign the user the necessary privelleges to use AdminDirectory