# Listing AdminDirectory users pagination (pageToken = page.nextPageToken) not functioning properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I am usning this code I found here >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161549/how-to-get-access-token-for-admin-directory-userlist-api to retrieve the email addresses of all users in our domain, and it is going into an infinite loop. When I printed the output, the code is printing the same 100 users over and over again when we have over 1500+ users.

I tried adding `Utilities.sleep(1000);`, up to 20 seconds in different points in my code and still the same results.

```
 function myFunction() {

  var loggedUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var domain = loggedUser.split('@')[1];
  var pageToken;
  var emails = [];
  do {
    
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=' + domain;
    var options = {
      "method": "get",
      "pageToken": pageToken,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      "contentType": "application/json",
    }
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(res);
    var page = JSON.parse(res);
    //Logger.log(page);
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log(user.primaryEmail);
        emails.push(user.primaryEmail);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  
}
```

This is driving me nuts, I searched everywhere, what am I dping wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getDomainUserList() {
  var users = [];
  var options = {
    
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 100,
    projection: 'basic', // Fetch basic details of users
    viewType: 'domain_public',
    orderBy: 'email', // Sort results by users
  };

  do {
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options);
    response.users.forEach(function (user) {
      users.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail]);
    });

    // For domains with many users, the results are paged
    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      options.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (response.nextPageToken);
  Logger.log(users);
  
  
}
```

This function should consider the next page token and retrieve all users from the domain.

Comment: Thank you!
That worked like a charm as is, I even avoided the need to use that annoying `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`